# SwiftUI and Catalyst: [API] cannot add handler to 3 from 3 - dropping

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

After converting my SwiftUI project to Catalyst I get this strange error message on the console:

> [API] cannot add handler to 3 from 3 - dropping

This happens when a view is scrolled, even in release mode, and quite a lot, probably every frame. It seems the whole logging slows the app down.

I am sorry to be so unspecific, I just don't know where to start from here.
(Except of filing a bug of course)

Has anyone had a similar experience? Where and when?
Is there maybe a workaround?

There is a thread in the Apple Forum, which is not solving the problem at all:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/719267

I have nothing found here nor by google.

Xcode is 14.2 macOS 13.2.1

Comment: Is anything broken? why do you worry about this?

Comment: "Is anything broken?" That's the question I am worried about. Is there anything that can be done on my side?

--- "Why do you worry about this?" Well, at least the message is spamming the device logs at 60 fps when scrolling, even when compiled in release mode. So, I assume, it affects performance in some way...

Comment: Well, error messages are only meaningful if you know their context. In this case we don't know the context (since it's coming from some internal Apple's API). It could be a silly debug message, someone forgot to turn off, or a bug. Either way there's nothing you can do about it, except for submitting a bug to apple. But if you actually have some issue, this could be a red herring, which makes you concentrate on this instead of the actual problem (if you have one).

Comment: same question and zero idea how to answer this one nor make the question more precise.

Comment: I'm seeing this in a UIKit Objective-C app so it's not specific to SwiftUI. Happens to me in a few different table view controllers while scrolling.

Comment: I have this in a UIKit using Swift 4.2… This may not have been happening in Xcode 14.0… for me.

Comment: For me the issue is caused by a TextField. This can be bound to either String or Float and NumberFormatter. It gets spammed when the value is changed, e.g. by a Slider, and causes bad performance. Removing the TextField hides the message. With 18 controls on the screen the app is crawling.
@State var a: Float = 0
TextField("1-99", value: $a, formatter: NumberFormatter())
Slider(value: $a, in: 0...99, step: 1)

Comment: I was seeing this in a [SplitView](https://github.com/stevengharris/SplitView) implementation I did, when running with Mac Catalyst. I came to the conclusion it is just a bit of harmless but annoying logging that was left in by mistake. I can report that it is gone as of XCode 15 Beta 6 running on MacOS 14 Sonoma Beta 5.

Comment: @SteveHarris this is only compelling reason to switch to Xcode 15 I've heard so far ;)